# Store passwords in a text file… is it really much worse than a password manager?

Tags: passwords, password-management

**My idea:**

Storing my passwords in a text file kept on Dropbox and accessed through a python script to quickly retrieve the password for the site I want to access.

**My motives:**

I want to be platform-independent as much as possible (currently, my passwords are stored in Safari's integrated password manager). Also I don't want to use any third party services, free or otherwise, just to store my passwords. I try to be as minimalist as possible even in my online life.

**My reasoning:**

Firstly, all the passwords for my core services (gmail, apple id, bank, dropbox) are long, random, and only stored offline in my brain + I use two-factor authentication on all of them. So it's not like I am devising a system that needs to keep my most prized assets. **The text file would only include passwords for less important websites and services.** The worst that could happen if someone were to get access to the text file is that he posts stupid questions online under my name :D …something I don't think professional hackers usually do.

Furthermore, in order to access the text file containing the passwords, you would need to get into my dropbox (which is protected by a strong password + two-factor authentication), get into my mac (which is protected by a strong password), or  access my hard disk (which is encrypted through FileVault).

Also, if someone breaks into my mac they are gonna have access to the passwords kept in safari anyway. Soooo… what am I missing?

PS: keep in my that I don't know anything about cyber security, encryption, or anything like that. I am not looking for a technical answer that I wouldn't be able to understand. Thanks.

Comment: You are effectively removing one factor from two-factor authentication if the file is really going to be plain text. A much better solution would be to encrypt it, and have your Python script decrypt it. You should have a strong encryption key, obviously.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point. What do you mean by removing one factor? I am removing one factor from what, exactly?

Comment: If you have 2FA that's password plus (e.g.) token. If your password leaks, only the token remains.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my post carefully. 2FA is used only for the most important passwords, which wouldn't be saved inside the text file.

Comment: That's not clear at all. Now that you explained it I can see that you are trying to convey this in your question, too.

Comment: Is the password for dropbox stored in plain text or do you enter it manually? If it's stored in plain text than, as @tripleee pointed out, you risk a leak.

Comment: Anyway, the idea that posting some stupid stuff in your name is the worst that could happen is a common and extremely dangerous misconception. Hackers don't typically care about using your identity directly, they want it so they can pivot to a more privileged account.

Comment: I'll edit the question in order to make it clearer: apple id, dropbox, gmail, and bank passwords ARE NOT stored in any text file, password manager or anything else. I memorize them and that's it.

Comment: The other dangerous assumption here is that there are some places where it's safe to store stuff in plaintext. Every new password leak is more proof that there is not. Follow https://haveibeenpwned.com for a while if you need concrete proof. What encrypting the file buys you is that it's not automatically game over and a massive failure if somebody manages to obtain a copy.

Comment: But this is exactly what I was trying to convey in my post (maybe it wasn't clear because I'm inexperienced in this stuff, or maybe because English in not my first language): do I really need to worry about encrypting a file that contains passwords in which no serious hacker would actually be interested? My stackexchange account? my instagram account? Isn't it enough to have them in a text file that's still behind several levels of security?

Comment: You can't have too much security. Somebody who found that file and decided you deserve whatever they can think up can turn your life into a regular hell, regardless whether you currently think those accounts are unimportant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is simple: **It's insecure.**

You claimed that you did not have any technical expertise and did not want to be bothered with answers you would not understand, so I will not bother you with cryptography.

Simply put, you have no disadvantage of using a password manager, and you only put yourself at risk if you do not follow this advice.

---

If you are interested in the technical aspects as well, I will explain them as simple as I can.

When you store your password in a password manager, the passwords are not stored in plain text. They are encrypted with a strong key (called "Data Encryption Key", or "DEK" for short), which again is protected by your password that you remember (the "Key Encryption Key", or "KEK").

If an attacker steals the data of your password manager, that data alone is useless. It is indistinguishable from a random sequence of zeroes and ones.

In order to make use of the data, an attacker would need to do one of two things:

1. Guess the Data Encryption Key.
   This is generally believed to be impossible within the lifespan of your universe. An attacker could buy *all* the computers there are in the world and start guessing keys, they would never find it.
2. Guess the Key Encryption Key.
   The Key Encryption Key is the password you use to "unlock" your Password Manager. What it actually does is decrypt your Data Encryption Key, and this is done with a very, VERY slow function. The reason it is very slow is because it is designed to be slow, which means that an attacker could not make it go faster if he wanted to.

As a result, someone stealing your Password Manager database would still result in your passwords being safe, as long as you used a strong passphrase when setting it up.

Comment: Could you tell me specifically how is having the passwords inside a text file different than having them stored inside Safari? Again, I'm no expert, but if you want to access the text file you either have to know my mac password or my dropbox password. If you know my mac password you can access passwords saved in Safari just as well. So…?

Comment: When you store them in your browser, your OS keychain or a password manager, those files are encrypted. This means, they are brought into a format which is unreadable unless you know the key to decrypt them. Think of it like a piece of paper with your passwords written on it, put in a box with a padlock, and the key on your person. An attacker would have to steal the box **and** pick the lock, instead of just having to steal the box.

Comment: But my hard disk is encrypted as well. So, if I understand correctly, the increase in risk is only because, if my Dropbox account is compromised, someone would have access directly to the file, which would not be encrypted. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @David42 Not just that, what about malicious actors at drop box? or if drop box were to log out data? or if an exploit to gain access to drop box files themselves without gaining access to accounts was found?

Comment: @David42 No, full disk encryption has no impact on this. Using Full Disk Encryption will not encrypt files in Dropbox. Why? Because in the eyes of the "user" and Dropbox, the files are there in plain text. You can verify this by opening Dropbox on your phone and you will see the file in plain text.

Comment: @MechMK1 it's probably also worth noting that since password managers have likely been audited/pen tested and exposed to public, they're likely much stronger than any *custom* password manager OP would make

Comment: @David42 Furthermore, you assumed that the only way to gain access to files on your Mac is by guessing your password. This is not the case. It's akin to believing that the only way into your house is the front door, while a thief can just smash a window and crawl in that way. An attacker can steal your data while your PC is running, e.g. by using an exploit in a vulnerable application.

Comment: @ExpiredData I get what you are saying, but I'd argue that one could say the same about any password manager, not just dropbox. It's a matter of trusting dropbox with my passwords vs trusting someone else.

Comment: @David42 Password managers can be offline as well. Keepass, for instance, is offline and you do not need to "trust" anyone.

Comment: @MechMK1 Yes. What I meant is that dropbox files synced to my hard disk are encrypted. If someone had access to my mac while logged in (maybe through malware, as you pointed out) then dropbox files would be not encrypted and freely accessible.

Comment: @David42 Maybe, except the password managers will likely conform to various additional constraints by the nature of them being password managers. E.g. they are more likely to be audited thoroughly in the specific domain of keeping your passwords secured than dropbox is. On top of this, there may be things that drop box don't care about that a password manager might. For example, a password manager would aim to guard against [Side channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack), where dropbox may not

Comment: @David42 If the file is encrypted, then it's not a plain text file. What you are doing is essentially a bare-bones password manager from scratch. I *highly* encourage you not to do this on your own, but instead use a properly tested password manager (e.g. like Keepass).

Comment: @MechMK1 Sorry, I didn't see your edited answer until now. Now I have a clearer picture of the problem. My only doubt left is this: I understand that encryption adds a layer of safety even if the data itself is compromised… but in what scenario could the data on my dropbox be compromised? A data leak from their servers? A malicious application on my mac? To me, these scenarios seem a bit unlikely. Could you elaborate a bit more on this? Thanks.

Comment: @David42 It is impossible to say if data on Dropbox or your Mac has been compromised. Encryption isn't designed to protect you from compromise, nor to detect it. Encryption is designed to keep your secrets confidential in case of compromise, as long as your key is reasonable secure.

Comment: Yes, what I said is that It doesn't seem likely to me that my dropbox data is compromised, hence encryption seems less important. Anyway, I got the information I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @David42 The point I am trying to get to is that you can't know, and encrypting sensitive data (like your credentials) is considered best practice. If you deviate from best practice, this is a risk. You have to justify yourself if this is a risk worth taking.